# roboearth: record a object: can't receive point clouds

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition, roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Currently I'm working with the roboearth recording a 3D model object.

I use the kinect attached with turtlebot. Instead of following the record_and_upload_object tutorial, I find my own way starting the kinect through turtlebot:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup kinect.launch
```

Then i run the rviz, set Point Cloud2's topic to "/camera/rgb/points", and Color Transformer to "RGB8", I can see the colored scene.
But the Color Transformer can't be set to "RGB8" if the topic is set to "/camera/depth/points", as said in the tutorial.
Also there's no topic "/camera/depth_registered/points", even i can be sure the depth registration is enabled:

```
>rosparam get /openni_camera/depth_registration
true
```

In the roboearth stack, I modified several source code files as well:

1. modified roboearth/object_scanning/re_object_recorder/src/mainwindow.cpp:
   original code:

ros::param::get("/camera/driver/depth_registration", depth_registration_enabled);

since the param "/camera/driver/depth_registration" doesn't exist in electric turtlebot, I changed it to :

```
ros::param::get("/openni_camera/depth_registration", depth_registration_enabled);
```

2. modified roboearth/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box/include/ar_kinect/ar_kinect.h:
   original code:

const std::string cameraImageTopic_ = "/camera/depth_registered/image";
const std::string cameraInfoTopic_  = "/camera/depth_registered/camera_info";
const std::string cloudTopic_ = "/camera/depth_registered/points";

changed code:

```
const std::string cameraImageTopic_ = "/camera/depth/image";
const std::string cameraInfoTopic_  = "/camera/depth/camera_info";
const std::string cloudTopic_ = "/camera/depth/points";
```

3. modified ccny_vision/ar_pose/include/ar_pose/ar_multi.h and ar_single.h

   original code:

const std::string cameraImageTopic_ = "/usb_cam/image_raw";

const std::string cameraInfoTopic_  = "/usb_cam/camera_info";

changed code:

```
const std::string cameraImageTopic_ = "/camera/rgb/image_raw";

const std::string cameraInfoTopic_  = "/camera/rgb/camera_info";
```

then i run the command:

```
rosrun ar_bounding_box ar_kinect
```

and got error message, the service can't be started:

```
[ INFO] [1330682463.131323897]:     Publish transforms: 1
[ INFO] [1330682463.146369212]:     Publish visual markers: 1
[ INFO] [1330682463.223120422]:     Threshold: 100
[ INFO] [1330682463.243390517]: Marker Pattern Filename: /home/te/ros/roboearth/stacks/roboearth/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box/data/objects_kinect
[ INFO] [1330682463.256355901]: Marker Data Directory: /home/te/ros/roboearth/stacks/roboearth/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box
[ INFO] [1330682463.256521164]: Subscribing to info topic
[ INFO] [1330682463.517989718]: *** Camera Parameter ***
--------------------------------------
SIZE = 640, 480
Distortion factor = 0.000000 0.000000 -0.000000 1.000000
525.00000 0.00000 319.50000 0.00000 
0.00000 525.00000 239.50000 0.00000 
0.00000 0.00000 1.00000 0.00000 
--------------------------------------
[ INFO] [1330682463.518104974]: Opening Data File /home/te/ros/roboearth/stacks/roboearth/object_scanning/ar_bounding_box/data/objects_kinect
[ INFO] [1330682463.518196987]: About to load 6 Models
[ INFO] [1330682463.518231050]: Read in No.1
[ INFO] [1330682463.518678755]: Read in No.2
[ INFO] [1330682463.519101924]: Read in No.3
[ INFO] [1330682463.519506378]: Read in No.4
[ INFO] [1330682463.519930962]: Read in No.5
[ INFO] [1330682463.520328178]: Read in No.6
[ INFO] [1330682465.177885566]: Subscribing to image and cloud topics
**Failed to find a field named: 'rgb'. Cannot convert message to PCL type.
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pcl::InvalidConversionException'
  what():  Failed to find a field named: 'rgb'. Cannot convert message to PCL type.
Aborted**
```

**When i run the object recording gui, I can see the green polar, but no piont clouds.**

Anyone has idea how to fix this problem??
Thanks very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28935/roboearth:-record-a-object:-can%27t-receive-point-clouds/) by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2012-03-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error message (and also the one in rviz) indicates that the pointcloud topic ar_bounding_box subscribes to is the wrong one, i.e. one without RGB information.

Revert your changes and try it like this

```
rosrun ar_bounding_box ar_kinect /camera/depth_registered/camera_info:=/camera/depth/camera_info /camera/depth_registered/points:=/camera/rgb/points
```

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on 2012-03-02**:
now I can start the ar_bounding_box without error. Can I modified the code to :
const std::string cameraInfoTopic_  = "/camera/depth/camera_info";
const std::string cloudTopic_ = "/camera/rgb/points";    so i don't have to run the long launch command?

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-03-02**:
Yes, that should work. I just also added a launch file which does the remapping for you, in ar_bounding_box/launch/ar_kinect_turtlebot.launch.

**Comment by [Gemini Ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/1762/gemini-ma/) on 2012-03-02**:
Nice. I've checked out that launch file. Thanks for the quick response!